# Efficiency using triggers inside attached database with SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite

**Situation**

I'm using multiple storage databases as attachments to one central "manager" DB.

- The storage tables share one pseudo-`AUTOINCREMENT` index across all storage databases.
- I need to iterate over the shared index frequently.
- The final number and names of storage tables are not known on storage DB creation.
- On some signal, a then-given range of entries will be deleted.
- It is vital that no insertion fails and no entry gets deleted before its signal.
- Energy outage is possible, data loss in this case is hardly, if ever, tolerable. Any solutions that may cause this (in-memory databases etc) are not viable.
- Database access is currently controlled using [strands](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html). This takes care of sequential access.
- Due to the high frequency of `INSERT` transactions, I must trigger WAL checkpoints manually. I've seen journals of up to 2GB in size otherwise.

**Current solution**

I'm inserting datasets using parameter binding to a precreated statement.

```
INSERT INTO datatable VALUES (:idx, ...);
```

Doing that, I remember the start and end index. Next, I bind it to an insert statement into the registry table:

```
INSERT INTO regtable VALUES (:idx, datatable);
```

My query determines the datasets to return like this:

```
SELECT MIN(rowid), MAX(rowid), tablename
FROM (SELECT rowid,tablename FROM entryreg LIMIT 30000)
GROUP BY tablename;
```

After that, I query

```
SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE rowid >= :minid AND rowid <= :maxid;
```

where I use predefined statements for each `datatable` and bind both variables to the first query's results.

This is too slow. As soon as I create the registry table, my insertions slow down so much I can't meet benchmark speed.

**Possible Solutions**

There are several other ways I can imagine it can be done:

1. Create a view of all indices as a `UNION` or `OUTER JOIN` of all table indices. [This can't be done persistently on attached databases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410180/sqlite-view-across-multiple-databases)
2. Create triggers for `INSERT`/`REMOVE` on table creation that fill a registry table. [This can't be done persistently on attached databases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392219/trigger-in-sqlite-different-database)
3. Create a trigger for `CREATE TABLE` on database creation that will create the triggers described above. [Requires user functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484259/sqlite-create-table-on-trigger)

**Questions**

Now, before I go and add user functions (something I've never done before), I'd like some advice if this has any chances of solving my performance issues.

- Assuming I create the databases using a separate connection before attaching them. Can I create views and/or triggers on the database (as `main` schema) that will work later when I connect to the database via `ATTACH`?
- From what it looks like, a trigger `AFTER INSERT` will fire after every single line of insert. If it inserts stuff into another table, does that mean I'm increasing my number of transactions from 2 to 1+N? Or is there a mechanism that speeds up triggered interaction? The first case would slow down things horribly.
- Is there any chance that a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (I know that I need to [create it from other `JOIN` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite)) is faster than filling a registry with insertion transactions every time? We're talking roughly ten transactions per second with an average of 1000 elements (insert) vs. one query of 30000 every two seconds (query).

Answer (score 0):

Open the sqlite3 databases in multi-threading mode, handle the insert/update/query/delete functions by separate threads. I prefer to transfer query result to a stl container for processing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It might be possible to separate insert from query/delete (separating those two is not thread safe in my case according to [multithread doc](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)). Template containers had to be removed for compile-time performance (improvement factor 10-15). But you're planting an idea there... I'll test tomorrow when I get my hands back on the code.

Comment: After testing I've come to the conclusion that there is no really useful multi-connection setup for my use case. To prevent simultaneous write access to the same DB, I must make `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `wal_checkpoint` routines mutually exclusive. Also, I must prevent `DELETE` and my main `SELECT` scenario from mixing execution time, otherwise I risk data loss. That's effectively close to the single-strand solution I was using beforehand. Speeding up all routines (especially `SELECT`) for themselves seems to be the way to go. Thanks anyway for the hint!